# How to re.sub european street adress to remove letters/digits

Tags: python, string

I'm working with a df where streets must be transformed into the following:

Streets:

```
A. Jakšto g. 2
Stumbrų g. 26A
M. K. Paco g. 19
Birželio 23-iosios g. 15
Grigiškių m. Kovo 11-osios g. 43
Laisvės pr. 87
```

Would need to be transformed to:

```
A. Jakšto g.
Stumbrų g.
M. K. Paco g.
Birželio 23-iosios g.
Grigiškių m. Kovo 11-osios g.
Laisvės pr
```

.

Yes, I know this isn't a place where someone could do the work for me - everything is Google'able, but I'm feeling really stuck here, even while reading the documentations ^^

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what is the type of `streets`?

Comment: @ManaliKagathara string

Comment: @mrzo basically various re.sub options that remove digits from the end of the string, unfortunately, when the street ends with '26A' the code no longer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to remove the last string in your text.

**Demo:**

```
s = """A. Jakšto g. 2
Stumbrų g. 26A
M. K. Paco g. 19
Birželio 23-iosios g. 15
Grigiškių m. Kovo 11-osios g. 43
Laisvės pr. 87"""

print("\n".join(" ".join(i.split()[:-1]) for i in s.splitlines()))
```

**Output:**

```
A. Jakšto g.
Stumbrų g.
M. K. Paco g.
Birželio 23-iosios g.
Grigiškių m. Kovo 11-osios g.
Laisvės pr.
```

Or using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re  

s = """A. Jakšto g. 2A
Stumbrų g. 26A
M. K. Paco g. 19
Birželio 23-iosios g. 15
Grigiškių m. Kovo 11-osios g. 43
Laisvės pr. 87"""

print(re.sub(r"(\d+[A-Za-z]?)$", "", s, flags=re.M))
```